# QuickBooks SDK integration with QuickBooks desktop

Tags: quickbooks

My Client wants to send his eCommerce data to QuickBooks, I checked that we can use QuickBooks PHP SDK, to send data to QuickBooks: https://github.com/intuit/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK.

But my client using QuickBooks desktop.
My question is can I use the same SDK to sync data to QuickBooks desktop?

Comment: You should follow the QuickBooks PHP Web Connector.
https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/question/0D50f0000571Aze/quickbooks-desktop-integration-with-php

Answer (score 0):

> can i use the same SDK to sync data to QuickBooks desktop?

No. If you read the notes on that page, it says it's for QuickBooks Online, which you're not using (emphasis mine):

`PHP client for connecting to the   ****QuickBooks Online****   V3 REST API.`

But you can use this one instead:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Specifically, you may want to follow the quick-start:

- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Quick-Start

Which walks you through using the QuickBooks Web Connector, which Intuit also documents thoroughly over here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/get-started